# Android EditText under scroll view is scroll to out of screen while typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

In my layout file, I have an EditText, under scrollbar, User can write till 1000 character. I gave Fixed Height to it, when user try to enter text( more then 500 character), It slightly start scrolling to top, and after some time edit text become disappear. I can pulled down to it, but when ever it get focus again, it again scroll to top and disappear. There are lots of View In my screen so Page is quite longer.

Menifest File:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityName"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manage_job"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

My Layout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

//Other View are availble on top and bottom of edit textl̥
 <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_profileSummary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/squre_edittext"
                        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:overScrollMode="always"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:maxLength="1000"
                        android:maxLines="25"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Please help me, If you understand my problem.

Comment: Man did you find my answer helpful ?